# When ntfs.sys driver is loading?

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry, boot, ntfs

I'm learning how Windows 7 starts and I try to make sure that bootmgr do not uses ntfs for its purposes (to search winload.exe file for example).

While I have a little knowledge to analyze the code of bootmgr, I'm trying to determine when the driver ntfs.sys is loading.

For this purpose, I'm looking into the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Ntfs key, there is Group key with value "Boot File System", then I'm looking for this key into the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GroupOrderList key.

But there is no "Boot File System" key (but I found mention of it in subkeys of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot key).

I'm looking into the List key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder key and there is this key is present.

Also I run Sysinternals LoadOrder utility to see it, but there is no mention of ntfs driver in general, but there is mention of fs_rec key in "File System" group, but in registry there is no "File System" group in GroupOrderList (but I found it in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem key).

Obviously, it's more hard to understand.

Нow can I make the right conclusions to determine when the ntfs.sys driver is loading or where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Windows WPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx) and run this command:

> xbootmgr -trace boot -traceFlags
>   BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+FILE_IO+FILENAME+REGISTRY
>   -stackwalk profile+CSwitch+ReadyThread+DiskReadInit+DiskWriteInit+ImageLoad+ImageUnload+RegQueryKey+RegEnumerateKey+RegEnumerateValueKey+RegDeleteKey+RegCreateKey+RegOpenKey+RegSetValue+RegDeleteValue+RegQueryValue+RegQueryMultipleValue+RegSetInformation+RegFlush+RegVirtualize+RegCloseKey+RegHiveInit+RegHiveDestroy+RegHiveLink+RegHiveDirty
>   -resultPath C:\TEMP

After reboot stop the countdown, load the ETL into WPA.exe, [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx), Drag&drop the "Images" graph from [Graph explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448118.aspx) to the right side ([Analysis tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448080.aspx)) and activate the stack column. Now you an see which functions of the kernel loads the driver.

The command also captures Registry access, so you can look which keys are being accessed during boot.

Comment: I started testing and as I understand wpa.exe in wpt for windows 8/10 is xperfview.exe in wpt for windows 7 (I installed wpt ver. 4.8.7701 from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442), until I found information you described, but there really is a lot of data to study, thanks